# What is the difference between () and {} in bash for grouping output and commands

Tags: bash

Here, only the second echo feeds the grep.

```
$ echo a1; echo a2 | grep -o a
a1
a
```

Here both echoes do so.

```
$ { echo a1; echo a2 ;} | grep -o a
a
a
```

Here as well.

```
$ (echo a1; echo a2 )| grep -o a
a
a
```

So what is the difference between () and {}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The round parentheses introduce a subshell.

```
$ a=1; { a=2 ; echo $a ; } ; echo $a
2
2
$ a=1; ( a=2 ; echo $a ; ) ; echo $a
2
1
```

Mind you, that `$$` stays the same in the subshell because bash does not need to be reinitialized. `$BASHPID` changes, though.

Comment: In the context of the question it would be good to test `a=1; { a=2 ; echo $a ; } | cat ; echo $a` as well (and the same with `()`). What's the difference (if any) in this case?

Comment: I don't see what it should demonstrate.

Comment: In this case `{ }` will also introduce a subshell because of the pipeline. So in the context of the examples from the OP there is no difference. Or is there?

Comment: pipe is not important.